# Ant matches giving false positives

Tags: regex, ant-contrib

I am trying to process/skip tasks with the help of the matches task.
But I am getting "false positives", the matches returns true when I think it should return false.
Following code is being used:

```
<property name="moduleList" value="AP|MR"/>
<echo message="ModuleList is ${moduleList}" />
...some for loop here...
<echo message="Found ${zipFilename}" />
<if>
    <matches pattern="${moduleList}" string="${zipFilename}" />
    <then>
        <echo message="Creating ${zipFilename}" />
    </then>
    <else>
        <echo message="Skipping ${zipFilename}" />
    </else>
</if>
```

The zipfileName is determined by looping through a folder and taking basename of files, zipfileNames being encountered are AP, MR and VAP
The result of this piece of code are:

```
[echo] ModuleList is AP|MR
[echo] Found AP
[echo] Creating AP
[echo] Found MR
[echo] Creating MR
[echo] Found VAP
[echo] Creating VAP
[echo] Found eFormsPolicy
[echo] Skipping eFormsPolicy
```

So according to me VAP is a false positive.
Or is there something wrong with my matches?

AFAIK ant.regexp.regexpimpl is not set, so ant is using Jdk14Regexp implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you are getting the false positives because `VAP` ends with `AP`?  What if you changed your matches pattern to `^(${moduleList})$`?  When the moduleList is actually substituted in, it would become `^(AP|MR)$`, which would not match `VAP`.

Comment: +1 - despite its name, `<matches>` uses `Matcher.find()`, not `matches()`, and needs the `^` and `$` if you want to anchor the match to the ends of the string.

Comment: This was it, I suspected it had something to do with the regex, but my regex knowledge is not that great. (@Ian Through it's behaviour I also suspected it was using find)

Comment: One pitfall with this is that before an empty moduleList would match anything. Now it matches nothing. So I needed to add an `<or><equals arg1="${moduleList}" arg2="" /><matches goes here></or>` or fill moduleList with `.*` when empty